# In C. elegans, which neuron has the largest span, and why is it this large?

Tags: neuroscience

The model organism [C. elegans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caenorhabditis_elegans) is about 1 mm in length.  This is quite small.  In fact, some C. elegans neurons span >25% of the length of its body ([ref.](http://www.wormatlas.org/neuronalwiring.html)).

[image: Source: Wikipedia]

This observation leads me to the following question: Which neuron in C. elegans has the largest span, and why is it this large?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am a member of [OpenWorm.org](http://www.openworm.org), an open-source project that aims to simulate a C. elegans cell-by-cell. I didn't know the answer to this myself off the top of my head, but I have access to a number of folks who have been working hard on C. elegans anatomy for the last couple of years so I went ahead and asked them this question [on our discuss mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/openworm-discuss/-GmHGJIZ5fQ). Thanks to Chris Grove and Tim Busbice for providing the answer that I am reporting below:

*Chris Grove*:

> Finding the neuron with the largest span partly depends on your
>   definition of "length" in this context. In terms of largest amount of
>   total axon/dendrite length, this would most probably be the PVDL/PVDR
>   sensory neurons. They produce a large number of branches of dendrites
>   that act to perceive mechano and thermo-sensation. See the [WormAtlas
>   page here](http://wormatlas.org/neurons/Individual%20Neurons/PVDframeset.html).

*Tim Busbice*:

> If by "length" one means, absolute longest extension from head to
>   tail, that's a tougher call, as there are several that extend from the
>   head to the tail. An example of these are the AVDL/AVDR command
>   interneurons, that function as touch modulators for backward
>   locomotion induced by head-touch, and also drive backward movement of
>   the animal along with driver cell AVA neuron, AVE and A-type motor
>   neurons.

You can find a lot of info on C. elegans anatomy on [WormAtlas](http://wormatlas.org/index.html) and on an [OpenWorm data spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Avt3mQaA-HaMdHZWLWJEMkdrSGtIX0FMUlh2LXhXWnc#gid=0) in which we are consolidating detailed anatomy data from different sources.

Also I would advise checking out the [OpenWorm Browser](http://browser.openworm.org/) - a web-based 3D viewer that you can use to explore the C. elegans anatomy cell-by-cell (the 3D model was developed by Chris Grove, see [VirtualWorm](http://caltech.wormbase.org/virtualworm/) for details). For instance you can easily search for those "longest" neurons mentioned above! Screenshot of one of them selected (AVDL) below:

[image: AVDL neuron]

Hope this helped!

Comment: Awesome answer!  I meant length in Tim Busbice's sense, since these types of neurons cause havoc for my network analysis.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped - keep in mind AVDL/R are among the longest in that sense, but there are many neurons that span from head to tail, such as CANL/R [ http://www.wormatlas.org/neurons/Individual%20Neurons/CANframeset.html ].